# How to enable database cache in my java application

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, caching

I have a scenario where i have a database which will be updated at any time by end user... my java application need to cache the data once any change in the database is done? How is it possible? Some one help me in clearing this issue?

I would like to know how to cache the database data once any updates is made in the database?

Comment: MySQL cache is enabled on the MySQL server. read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html

Comment: @RaymondNijland cache should be automatically updated , if there is any change in the database. that is my scenerio

Answer (score 0):

You can register a stored procedure as trigger that notifies your Java application about the update. Read about triggers here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Your question can be interpreted in different ways:

- You want to minimize the latency between update in the database and the cache update. Eventual consistency is okay.
- The cache is kept consistent with the database content

The latter is much more difficult to achieve. If consistency is required, then, at some point, the database transaction must wait until the application is notified and has acknowledged. You will run into lots of interesting questions in the area of distributed computing.